# Started AMI but Terminated the EC2 instance before the AMI was completed. Will the AMI finish?

Tags: amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

I started creating an AMI from an EC2 instance.  The AMI had not yet completed and I Terminated the instance.
Snapshot 1 is 30 GB, 99/100% Unavailable
Snapshot 2 is 900 GB, 0/100% Unavailable

Will the AMI complete successfully?  Or am I stuck starting the whole process over (the instance was orig spun up from a shared AMI)?

Comment: Didn't finish until the following day.  I know the first time a snapshot runs it takes longer and subsequent ones are diffs, but I didn't realize big volumes take that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will eventually finish. The progress percentage number actually shows how much of the snapshot data has been successfully transferred to S3, which can take hours or even days depending on the size of the volume.

Comment: Thanks--it did finally update progress.  Took hours just to show 8% on the 900 GB drive.  I had never seen those take so long, hence my fear it was stuck due to my action.